# how to get the linux kernel directory from http://source.android.com?

Tags: linux, kernel, android-source

The default download seems not to contain the kernel directory while use the prebuilt linux kernel image. Does any one know how to get the linux kernel directory? I have googled and tried some methods but they did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how to use git right?

Here : 
https://android.googlesource.com/

Comment: Hi,first thanks for your reply. I have tried this link but it asks me password. By searching,  I have found this command "git clone git://android.git.kernel.org/kernel/common.git". But it shows that the connection is refused. Can you give me more instructions ? Thanks :>

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://android.googlesource.com/ as the repositories moved away from kernel.org to Google's own servers (~2011).

There are a couple of repositories named "kernel/*". Each one is for a different device. For instance, the one used in the emulator is the "kernel/goldfish".

Once you click in any one of them, at the top of the repository page you'll get a "git clone" command to download them individually.